# get autoform non-collection forms method return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I want to use meteor-autoform for my non-collection forms. I try [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#non-collection-forms) approach but I want to get method return value and display it on client. Please guide me how to do this.

This is my schema (**common.js**):

```
Schema = {};
Schema.echoSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    echoText: {
        type: String,
        label: "Echo Text",
        max: 50
    }
});
```

This is my code on the Client (**client.js**):

```
Template.showEcho.helpers({
    getEchoFormSchema: function() {
        return Schema.echoSchema;
    }
});
```

This is my code on the Server (**server.js**):

```
Meteor.methods({
  echoMethod: function (doc) {
    check(doc, Schema.echoSchema);
    return doc.echoText;
  },
});
```

This is my form template (**showEcho.html**):

```
    <template name="showEcho">
        {{#autoForm schema=getEchoFormSchema id="echoForm" type="method" meteormethod="echoMethod"}}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Echo Form</legend>
                    {{> afQuickField name="echoText"}}
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
        {{/autoForm}}

        <p>
            // How To Show Echo Text HERE??
            Text = ???????????????????
        </p>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoform hooks is your friend

[Read about it here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks)

Add this to your client code:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    'echoForm': {
        after: {
           method: function(error, result) {
              console.log("after");
              if (result) {
                 return Session.set('result', result);
              }
           }
        }
     }
});
```

In your Template js file, create a helper to return Session.get 'result'

```
Template.showEcho.helpers({
  text: function() {
    return Session.get('result')

  }
});
```

Template html file:

```
<template name="showEcho">
    {{#autoForm schema=getEchoFormSchema id="echoForm" type="method" meteormethod="echoMethod"}}
       .
       .
       .
       . 
    {{/autoForm}}

    <p>
        {{text}}
    </p>
</template>
```

Comment: text returns the object, but you'll get the basics

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. Please change after: { 'echoMethod': ... to after: {method:.... // and why this is return an object??

Comment: In your Meteor.method I thought you returned the whole doc , don't know why I assumed that! I was wrong.